# The largest “root-sum” in a four-square representation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, sums-of-squares

Well-known is the fact that every natural number can be represented as the sum of four integer squares — this proposition is often called [Lagrange’s four-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem).

Perhaps less well-known is the fact that every odd natural number can be represented as the sum of four integer squares *such that the sum of those integers is every odd number from $1$ to “the maximum”*. For example,
$$
17 = (\pm 3)^2 + (\pm 2)^2 + (\pm 2)^2+0^2 = (\pm 4)^2 + (\pm 1)^2 + 0^2 + 0^2,
$$
where $(-3)+2+2=1$ and $3+2+(-2)=3$ and $4+1=5$ and $3+2+2=7$, and the smallest set of roots summing to $9$ would have a sum of squares $\ge 19$.

This theorem was stated by Pollock, who — in the classical way — provided voluminous evidence and fascinating tables (see, for example, [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/108505)), but no algebraic proof, as far as I can tell.

I have two questions related to this second result.

> **Question 1:** Has a proof ever been published of Pollock’s statement?
>
> **Questions 2:** Is there a formula which explicitly gives “the maximum” root-sum for any odd natural number $n$?

With regard to the second question: It is trivial, of course, to calculate the *upper bound* of such a “maximum”, since $n \le (\sqrt{n})^2 + a^2+b^2+c^2$. But I’m hoping there is a formula which gives the largest possible root-sum.

Comment: For reference, see the paragraph about Pollock toward the bottom of page 292 at https://books.google.com/books?id=dO7C02z4LlcC&pg=PA291&lpg=PA291&dq=pollock+sum+of+four+squares&source=bl&ots=bQ5fZJlNK_&sig=PrQgMys_k1wMLoM5yhEOAhHiZYo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj49JDhyoLPAhUCgj4KHYIACAMQ6AEIIDAB#v=onepage&q=pollock%20sum%20of%20four%20squares&f=false